# JavaScript settings are on but I still have issues with web sites using JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I have two computers that are the same at home except I have installed Adobe Acrobat 9 Pro Extended on my main computer along with the 2010 Outlook (Beta). I have issues when I log into a website that uses pop up calendars to select the date. I pasted it below. I checked my other computer and it is fine. I've checked the Java setting and they are correct. I am at a loss. Any suggestions?

```
Webpage error details

User Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/4.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; Media Center PC 6.0; HPDTDF; OfficeLiveConnector.1.4; OfficeLivePatch.1.3; eMusic DLM/4; .NET4.0C) Timestamp: Mon, 26 Jul 2010 22:03:59 UTC

Message: 'CalendarPopup' is undefined Line: 390 Char: 2 Code: 0

Message: 'CalendarPopup' is undefined Line: 410 Char: 2 Code: 0
```

Comment: What browser? Does it happen with other browsers on the same computer? Have you tried clearing the browser cache/cookies? Have you tried uninstalling and reinstalling the browser?

Comment: Thanks for the responce...Chrome, Explorer, explorer (64) and Firefox. Firefox and chrome do not say there is an error but the calendars do not work just like in explorer. I am leaving my ofice but my email comes direct to my phone if you do not mind e-mailing me.    m.roland.btbinc@gmail.com

Answer (score 0):

First of all java and javascript are 2 totally different things... Probably your pop-ups are blocked.. you can try (in firefox) Preferences->Content and then untick Block pop-up windows.
Also this is not the place to leave give away your email.Finally the fact that ACROBAT or Outlook are installed in any of two computers doesn't seem relevant at all...good luck

Comment: Thanks for the advice...pop-ups are not blocked. The mention about Acrobat and Outlook are because they are the only difference that this computer has had done different than the other identacle computer that is acting normal.